# Hooking up my power switch/reset switch/LEDs

Tags: computer-building, voltage

I'm working on building a computer (first time for me).  There are several plugs that I need to connect to the motherboard (Power LED, reset switch, etc).  Of the two wires, they are either:

1. Color and white (reset switch, power LED, HDD LED)
2. red and black (speaker, power switch)

The manual for the motherboard has a nice diagram of where to plug them in, but has them labeled + or -.  Which colors are positive, and which are negative?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For reset swtich and power switch, it does not matter.

By electrical convention, red is positive, black is negative. For the others, generally I think colour is positive, white is negative.

For the connections you have listed, you will not damage your system if you connect them up backwards; the lights simply won't work.

Comment: Thanks!  It's good to know this won't damage anything.  Being new to computer building, it's hard to know what parts I need to be really careful with, and I can relax about.

Comment: My motherboard manual specifically urges to take notice of the + and - to plug the power and rest switches, whereas you say this does not matter. Why would the manual say differently?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier I can offer no electrical explanation. Switches break or make an electrical connection. They don't have polarity. Perhaps the advice is in a context that would include the LEDs?

Answer (score 66):

In most motherboard cables there is a little triangle that marks the positive side. See the picture below:

[image: Motherboard cable positive side]

Comment: Ah, that's good to know.  It's likely this is a new thing, since I would have noticed those.  A lot can change in motherboard design in 4 years!

Comment: Just a general thought, why didn't they just use a plus sign instead of a triangle?

Comment: @Hind-D yes indeed, I have a Thermaltake F31 Supressor (great case btw) and most connectors have + / - on them, except the PW and RESET switches that oddly have the triangles - well we learn something everyday !

Comment: @Hind-D that'd be wayyyyyy too simple